# remove special character in a csv unix and fix the new line

Tags: shell, csv, unix, sql-loader

[image: Here is the Actual junk character screen shot]

Below is my sample data in the csv .

```
20160711,"M","N1","F","S","A","good data with.....some special character and space 
space ..
....","M","072","00126"

20160711,"M","N1","F","S","A","R","M","072","00126"
20160711,"M","N1","F","S","A","R","M","072","00126"
```

In above in a field I have good data along with junk data and line splited to new line .
I want to remove this special character (due to this special char and space,the line was moved to the next line) as well as merge this split line to a single line.

currently I am using something like below which is taking lots of time :

tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' | gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' MY_FILE.csv > MY_FILE.csv.tmp

attached a screenshot of original data in the file .

Comment: You could use `tr -c '[:print:]\r\n' ' ' <bad.csv >better.csv` to get rid of the non-printable chars, but detecting/removing automagically the erroneous line breaks would be tricky...

Comment: ...but  `sed '/[^"]$/ { N ; s/\n// } better.csv | sed '/[^"]$/ { N ; s/\n// } > even_better.csv` would cover *most* cases (i.e. would fail to trap an extra line break just after a random quote)

Comment: By special character do you mean a carriage return? You might have to look at the data in hex to see (try `od -cd` maybe). Could there be other "special characters"? Can you manipulate the file in unix or are you looking to do it in SQL*Loader only? Is the space along with the special character valid as the other records don't have the space?

Comment: Can you paste a section of actual data including the special character?

Comment: @Gary_W I have attached a sceen shot of the actual date ,have a look.

Comment: @Gary_W  , Yes I am currently manipulating the file in the unix ..

Comment: I'm afraid we need to see actual data pasted so we can view the control characters in an editor that supports hex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
tr -c '[:print:]\r\n' ' ' <bad.csv >better.csv
```

to get rid of the non-printable chars…

```
sed '/[^"]$/ { N ; s/\n// }' better.csv | sed '/[^"]$/ { N ; s/\n// }' >even_better.csv
```

would cover *most cases* (i.e. would fail to trap an extra line break just after a random quote)

– Samson Scharfrichter

Answer (score 0):

One problem that you will likely have with a traditional unix tool like `awk` is that while it supports field separators, it does not support quote+comma-style CSV formatting like the one in your screenshot or sample data.  Awk can separate fields in a record using a *field separator*, but it has no concept of quote armour around your fields, so embedded commas are also considered field separators.

If you're comfortable with that because none of your plaintext data includes commas, and none of your "non-printable" data includes commas by accident, then you can just consider the quotes to be part of the field. They're printable characters, after all.

If you want to join your multi-line records into a single line and strip any non-printable characters, the following awk one-liner might do:

```
awk -F, 'NF<10{$0=last $0;last=$0} NF<10{next} {last="";sub(/[^[:print:]]/,"")} 1' inputfile
```

Note that this works *except* in cases where the line break is between the last comma and the content of the last field because from awk's perspective an empty field is valid and there's no need to join. If this logic doesn't match your data, you get another fun programming task as a result. :)

Let's break out the awk script and see what it does.

```
awk -F, '             # Set comma as the field separator...
  NF<10 {             # For any lines that have fewer than 10 fields...
    $0=last $0        # Insert the last "saved" line here,
    last=$0           # and save the newly joined line for the next round.
  }
  NF<10 {             # If we still have fewer than 10 lines,
    next              # repeat.
  }
  {
    sub(/[^[:print:]]/,"")     # finally, substitute an empty string
  }                            # for all non-printables,
  1' inputfile                 # And print the current line.
```